# 0 height navigation bar still visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a portfolio website and wanted to have my work slide up onto the screen when you clicked portfolio, same way a nav bar would slide over when you click a menu icon. The code I have works for nav bars on the right and left, but for the bottom it still shows the block even with the height of 0

unfortunately using display:none and changing it to display:block with jquery removes the smooth animation of it sliding onto screen.

```
html

        <div id="portfolionav" class="portfolionav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" 
             onclick="closeNav2()">&#9755;</a>
            <a href="#">testing</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div id=bottom>
            <h1 onclick="openNav2()">PORTFOLIO</h1>
        </div>
```

```
css

        .portfolionav {
           height: 0;
           width: 100%;
           position: fixed;
           z-index: 3;
           bottom: 0;
           background-color: #111;
           overflow-x: hidden;
           transition: 0.5s;
           padding-top: 60px;
           display: block;
        }

        .portfolionav a {
           padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
           text-decoration: none;
           font-size: 25px;
           color: #818181;
           display: block;
           transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .portfolionav a:hover {
           color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        .portfolionav .closebtn {
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 25px;
           right: 75px;
           font-size: 36px;
           writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        }
```

```
javascript

        function openNav2() {
            document.getElementById("portfolionav").style.height = "100vh";
        }

        function closeNav2() {
            document.getElementById("portfolionav").style.height = "0";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use display: none instead of height.

Comment: only problem with this is that there is no longer a smooth animation of the div sliding up to fill the screen. It just snaps.

Answer (score 0):

Once the portfolio div is fixed, you can use the **top** property instead of cotroling the animation by the height. You also have to set the default height as 100vh.

So your `portfolionav` should be:

```
.portfolionav {
       height: 100vh;
       width: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       z-index: 3;
       top: 100vh;
       background-color: #111;
       overflow-x: hidden;
       transition: 0.5s;
       padding-top: 60px;
       display: block;
}
```

And your JavaScript functions:

```
function openNav2() {
  document.getElementById("portfolionav").style.top = "0";
}

function closeNav2() {
  document.getElementById("portfolionav").style.top = "100vh";
}
```

Now, you just have to adjust the hand-button as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can combined `height` and `paddingTop` for show and hide navigation because of padding it is showing when you set `height:0px;`

```js
function openNav2() {
debugger;
    document.getElementById("portfolionav").style.height = "100vh";
    document.getElementById("portfolionav").style.paddingTop = "60px";
}

function closeNav2() {
    document.getElementById("portfolionav").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("portfolionav").style.paddingTop = "0";
}
```

```css
 .portfolionav {
     height: 0;
     width: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 3;
     bottom: 0;
     background-color: #111;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     transition: 0.5s;
     padding-top: 0px;
     display: block;
  }

  .portfolionav a {
     padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 25px;
     color: #818181;
     display: block;
     transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .portfolionav a:hover {
     color: #f1f1f1;
  }

  .portfolionav .closebtn {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 25px;
     right: 75px;
     font-size: 36px;
     writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  }
```

```html
        <div id="portfolionav" class="portfolionav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" 
             onclick="closeNav2()">&#9755;</a>
            <a href="#">testing</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div id=bottom>
            <h1 onclick="openNav2()">PORTFOLIO</h1>
        </div>
```